# Can a function with suport on a finite interval have a Fourier transform which is zero on a finite interval?

Tags: fourier-analysis

If $f$ has support on $[-x_0,x_0]$ can its Fourier transform $\tilde{f}$ be zero on $[-p_0,p_0]$? If so, what is the maximum admissible product $x_0p_0$?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $f$ is not identically zero.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75405/on-functions-with-fourier-transform-having-compact-support/75417#75417), it is shown that if $f$ has compact support, then $\hat{f}$ is entire. A non-zero entire function cannot be zero on a set with a limit point. Thus, if $f=0$ on $[-p_0,p_0]$, then $p_0=0$, and therefore, the maximum of $x_0p_0=0$.