# How to evaluate $ \lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sum \limits_ {k=1}^n \frac{k^n}{n^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I can show that the following limit exists but
I am having difficulties to find it. It is
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^n}{n^n}$$
Can someone please help me?

Comment: How could you show that the limit exist?

Comment: @Siminore: The sum is very similar to $\int_{0}^{1}x^xdx$. Isn't it?

Comment: Numerically, for $n=1000$, I get 1.58098.

Comment: @Siminore: That happens to be only a little shy of the correct answer, $\dfrac{1}{1 - 1/e}$.

Comment: Probably. But the result is not $\int_0^1 x^x\, dx$.

Comment: For future reference, let me also add duplicate/similar answers that are not previously linked to this: [Nov 6 '13](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553895), [Sep 11 '14](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1379917).

Answer (score 38):

An asymptotic expansion can be obtained as below. More terms can be included by using more terms in the expansions of $\exp$ and $\log$.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k^n}{n^n}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\exp\left(n\log\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}\exp\left(n\log\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)+O\left(ne^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}\exp\left(-k-\frac{1}{2n}k^2+O\left(\frac{k^3}{n^2}\right)\right)+O\left(ne^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}e^{-k}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2n}k^2+O\left(\frac{k^3}{n^2}\right)\right)+O\left(ne^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}e^{-k}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}k^2+O\left(\frac{k^ 4}{n^2}\right)\right)+O\left(ne^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}e^{-k}-\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}k^2e^{-k}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{e}{e-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\frac{e(e+1)}{(e-1)^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Several steps use
$$
\sum_{k=n}^\infty e^{-k}k^m=O(e^{-n}n^m)
$$
which decays faster than any power of $n$.

Comment: Why $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n e^{-k}O\left(\frac{k^4}{n^2}\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ ?

Comment: @Norbert: Because $$\sum_{k=0}^ne^{-k}O\left(\frac{k^4}{n^2}\right)\le\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}k^4\right)O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ !

Comment: Thakns, I'll try to learn $O$-approach in future.

Comment: I personally think that $\ln(1-x)=-x-x^2/2+O(x^3)$ only holds for $x\prec1$, so you should break the summation into $0<k\le d(n)$ and $k>d(n)$, where $d(n)\prec n$. PS: $f(n)\prec g(n)\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)=0$.

Comment: Good approximation, where $\Theta_n(t)$ is not needed.

Comment: @FrankScience: Done. I did indeed forget the tail, which dies almost exponentially.

Comment: This still isn't quite correct. You can't use a Taylor expansion of $\log(1-k/n)$, because the upper bound on $k/n$ does not go to 0 as $n\to\infty$. However if you split the tail at e.g. $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$, this works.

Comment: @GenericHuman I've mentioned, see preceding comment.

Comment: @robjohn LOL. Omit the tail, just like the answer on *Concrete Mathematics*, which made me misunderstood for a long time.

Comment: @FrankScience: Yes, I hadn't really read your comment since robjohn said he had addressed the problem (plus $d(n)\prec n$ looks a lot like $d(n)<n$, so it doesn't stand out as much as $d(n)=o(n)$).

Comment: @GenericHuman I thought about using $o(f(n))$, but eventually I used $\prec$ because both $O$ and $o$ appear seems ambiguous.

Comment: @GenericHuman: For $0\le x\le\frac12$, $\left|\log(1-x)+x+x^2/2\right|\le x^3$, so $\log(1-x)=-x-x^2/2+O(x^3)$. The Taylor series for $\log$ is fine. I did have to adjust the upper limit of the sum for $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2n}k^2+O\left(\frac{k^3}{n^2}\right)\right)$

Comment: I really like this answer, Rob.  I published a paper on this sum several years ago (see, for example, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244657/value-of-lim-n-to-infty-frac1n2n-cdotsn-1nnn/244663#244663), and I've kept my eye out for alternative ways of getting the limiting expression.  Your answer here is one of my favorites.  It does a really nice job of handling the error terms.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: Thanks! I am a big fan of the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula. For polynomials, it is exact (in fact, in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156085), I give a condition for the EMS Formula to converge).

Comment: How did big O appeared in the third line @robjohn?

Comment: From the terms in the sum for $k\gt\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Yes, I know, I would like to understand the details.

Comment: $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=\sqrt{n}+1}^n\exp\left(n\log\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)&\le\overbrace{\quad\ \ n\quad\ \ \vphantom{\frac kn}}^{\le n\text{ terms}}\overbrace{\exp\left(n\left(-\frac kn\right)\right)}^{\log(1-x)\le -x}\\&\le ne^{-\sqrt{n}}\end{align}$$ since $k\ge\sqrt{n}$

Comment: It cleared very many things.

Comment: How did you find the first relation?

Comment: Substitute $k\mapsto n-k$.

Answer (score 28):

Just for reference: With aid of some fancy theorem, you can skip most of hard analysis. As in other answers, we begin by writing

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k}{n}\right)^n
\ \overset{k \to n-k}{=} \ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n
\ = \ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n \mathbf{1}_{\{k < n\}}, $$

where $\mathbf{1}_{\{k < n\}}$ is the indicator function which takes value $1$ if $k < n$ and $0$ otherwise. Now for each $0 \leq k < n$, utilizing the inequality $\log(1-x) \leq -x$ which holds for all $x \in [0,1)$ shows that

$$ \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n
= e^{n \log(1 - \frac{k}{n})}
\leq e^{-k}. $$

Since $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-k} < \infty$, by the dominated convergence theorem we can interchange the infinite sum and the limit:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k}{n}\right)^n
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n \mathbf{1}_{\{k < n\}}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-k}
= \frac{1}{1 - e^{-1}}. $$

Comment: Ah, so *this* is what mixedmath was alluding to. Very nicely done. (+1)

Comment: Maybe this is a basic question, but how did you get the first equality?

Comment: @user372003, I added a bit of details to my answer. But basically, I replaced the index $k$ by $n-k$.

Comment: Hi Sangchul!  I hope that you're doing well.  (+1) Unsure as to why this is not the overwhelmingly most useful answer.  It is clear and concise.

Answer (score 19):

Finally, I have suffered this proof. Consider functions
$$
f_n(x)=\left(1-\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{n}\right)^n\chi_{[0,n+1]}(x)
$$
Note that
$$
\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)} f_n(x)d\mu(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\int\limits_{[k,k+1)}\left(1-\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{n}\right)^nd\mu(x)=
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n
$$
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{n}\right)^n\cdot \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\chi_{[0,n+1]}(x)=e^{\lfloor x\rfloor}
$$
One may check that $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative functions, then using monotone convergence theorem we get
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)} f_n(x)d\mu(x)=
$$
$$
\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)d\mu(x)=
\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)} e^{\lfloor x\rfloor}d\mu(x)=
\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}
$$

Comment: You must justify the interchange of the limit and the sum in the second equality. One way to do this is to note that $(1-k/m)^m<(1-k/n)^n$ if $k+1\leq m<n$ and then to invoke the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: You could just use the sequence version of the [Monotone Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that

Comment: Could you compute the asymptotics, not just the limits. I'm very interested in such theory.

Comment: @FrankScience Why don't you use [Euler–Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)?

Comment: @Norbert Because yesterday I thought [Poisson summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) is more powerful in this problem than Euler-Maclaurin summation formula, where $\Theta_n(t)$ is periodic function of $t$.

Answer (score 7):

Let's notice a few things. All the terms are positive, bounded between $0$ and $1$, and there is a term that is exactly $1$. What about the next largest term?

So we ask ourselves what $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \dfrac{n-1}{n} \right)^n$ is, and after a little calculation we see that this limit is $1/e$. The 'next' term involves $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \dfrac{n-2}{n} \right)^n = e^{-2}$. So heuristically, we would expect the limit to be

$$1 + e^{-1} + e^{-2} + \dots = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{e}}$$

Working only a little harder, you can justify that this is the limit.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to prove that $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{k^n}{n^n}-e^{-k} \right)=0.$$

Comment: Sorry: the limit should be 1, in the previous comment.

Comment: @Siminore: Have you tried? It's really not bad at all, as long as you know the dominated convergence theorem and/or the monotone convergence theorem. In fact, that series is absolutely convergent, so you can do a whole lot of things to it

Comment: Yes, it's a matter of passing to the limit inside a series.

Answer (score 4):

$\sum_{k=1}^n(k/n)^n=\sum_{0<k\le n}(1-k/n)^n$, and let $a_k(n)=(1-k/n)^n$. For $0<k\le n^{1/3}$, we have
$$\ln a_k(n)=n\ln\left(1-\frac kn\right)=-n\left(\frac kn+O\left(\frac kn\right)\right)=-k+O\left(\frac{k^2}n\right)$$
thus
$$a_k(n)=e^{-k}\left(1+O\left(\frac{k^2}n\right)\right)$$
Let $b_k(n)=e^{-k}$, $c_k(n)=k^2e^{-k}/n$, we have $a_k(n)=b_k(n)+O(c_k(n))$ over $0<k\le n^{1/3}$. Thus, we have
$$\sum_{0<k\le n}a_k(n)=\sum_{k>0}b_k(n)+O(\Sigma_a(n))+O(\Sigma_b(n))+O(\Sigma_c(n))$$
where
$$\sum_{k>0}b_k(n)=\sum_{k>0}e^{-k}=\frac e{e-1}$$
and
\begin{align*}
\Sigma_b(n)&=\sum_{k>n^{1/3}}e^{-k}=O(e^{n^{1/3}})\\
\Sigma_a(n)&=\sum_{n^{1/3}<k\le n}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\le\sum_{n^{1/3}<k\le n}e^{-k}=O(e^{n^{1/3}})\\
\Sigma_c(n)&=\sum_{0<k\le n^{1/3}}e^{-k}k^2/n\le\sum_{k>0}e^{-k}k^2/n=O\left(\frac 1n\right)
\end{align*}
Hence, we have $\sum_{0<k\le n}(1-k/n)^n=e/(e-1)+O(1/n)$.

**Can anybody give a more accurate approximation?**
The key to the approximation is to find the asymptotics for $\sum_{k>0}\exp(-k-k^2/2n)$, like the Bell sum $\sum_{k>0}e^{-k^2/n}$.

**Edit** anon [pointed out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5148192#5148192) that it's theta function: $\sum_ke^{-(k+t)^2/n}$, so the Fourier series works pretty well for the asymptotics:
$$\Theta_n(t)=\sqrt{\pi n}\left(1+2e^{-\pi^2 n}(\cos2\pi t)+2e^{-4\pi^2 n}(\cos4\pi t)+2e^{-9\pi^2 n}(\cos6\pi t)+\cdots\right)$$
**But I have no idea about Fourier series because I know very little about calculus!**

Comment: In [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/164269), I show how to get more accuracy by including more terms in in the series for $\log$ and $\exp$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4451292).

Answer (score 3):

First, we can rewrite the formula:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^n}{n^n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i^n}{n^n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-i)^n}{n^n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n} \right)^n$$

We can easily prove the following inequality relations:

$$\frac{1}{\text{e}^i} - \frac{i^2}{n\text{e}^i} \le \frac{1}{\text{e}^i}\left(1-\frac{i}{n} \right)^i\le \left(1-\frac{i}{n} \right)^n \le \frac{1}{\text{e}^i} $$

Therefore, we can get

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\text{e}^i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i^2}{\text{e}^i}\le\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}  \right)^n \le \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\text{e}^i}$$

So

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\text{e}^i}-\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i^2}{\text{e}^i}\le\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n} \right)^n \le \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\text{e}^i}$$

We can easily know that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\text{e}^i} = \frac{\text{e}}{\text{e}-1}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i^2}{\text{e}^i} = \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i^2}{\text{e}^i}\right) = 0 \cdot \frac{\text{e}(\text{e}+1)}{(\text{e}-1)^3} = 0$$

Finally, we can get the answer:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^n}{n^n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}  \right)^n = \frac{\text{e}}{\text{e}-1}$$

For more details, you can watch my video on Bilibili, if you have learned Chinese.

Here is my video link: https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1yG411g7K1/