# Value of Limit and Sum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, real-numbers

Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left( \frac{k}{n}\right)^{n}$$

I can't compare it with similar series and I can't change it to Riemann's sum.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I've answered [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/164074), although the answer I gave there is quite different.

Answer (score 2):

For each $k\ge0$, $[n\gt k]\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n$ is non-decreasing in $n$, where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Therefore, by [monotone convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{e}{e-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find the question before, thanks a lot