# Find limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^n}{n^n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, limits

Now I want to find the limit 
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^n}{n^n}.$$
I try to use the Stolz theorem as follows:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^n}{n^n}=
  \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n k^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n(k^{n+1}-k^n)}{(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n}$$
$$=1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(k^{n+1}-k^n)}{(n+1)^{n+1}}.$$
It seems to deal with the summation like this form:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p,\text{with}\ p=n,n+1.$$
I have no way to deal this summation, any help and hint will welcome!

Comment: See also: [How to evaluate $ \lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sum \limits_ {k=1}^n \frac{k^n}{n^n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164074) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/164074).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: For fixed $k,$ $$\frac{(n-k)^n}{n^n}=\left(1-\frac{k}n\right)^n\to e^{-k}$$

---

Details:

Note that for $k=0...,n-1$ $$\log\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)=-\frac{k}{n}-\frac{k^2}{2n^2}-\cdots\leq -\frac{k}{n}$$

So $$\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n \leq e^{-k}$$

Then apply the dominated convergence theorem by defining:

$$f_n(k)=\begin{cases}0 & k\geq n\\ \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n& 0\leq k<n\end{cases}$$

Then $|f_n(k)|\leq g(k)=e^{-k}$ and for any $k,$ $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_n(k)\to g(k).$

Comment: How to deal with the double limit??

Comment: and the value of limit is ?.Numeric says: $\approx1.58$

Comment: the limit is $\frac{e}{e-1}\approx1.58$.

Comment: Could someone add a whole solution? I am interested in this limit aswell but I am not sure how to use the given hint to find the correct value.

Comment: @mrtaurho 1+1/e+1/e^2+・・・+1/e^n+・・・$=\frac{1}{1-1/e}=\frac{e}{e-1}$

Comment: Are you using Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem with countable measure here? Or something else?

Answer (score 10):

We have that

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^n}{n^n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac k n \right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( \frac {n-k} n \right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( 1-\frac {k} n \right)^n$$

then, following the suggestion given by [ComplexYetTrivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/570419/complexyettrivial), let consider

$$a_n=\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k<n}}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac {k} n \right)^n$$

which is strictly increasing and bounded indeed by AM-GM we have

- $\sqrt[n+1]{\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n \cdot 1} \leq \frac{n
     \left(1   - \frac{k}{n}\right) + 1}{n+1} = 1 - \frac{k}{n+1} $

and

- $\left( 1-\frac {k} n \right)^n=e^{n\log \left( 1-\frac {k} n
     \right)}=e^{n \left( -\frac {k} {n}-\frac {k^2} {2n^2}-\frac {k^3}
     {3n^3}-\ldots \right)}\le e^{-k}$

therefore by the monotone convergence theorem $a_n$ has finite limit and since for $k$ fixed

- $\left( 1-\frac {k} n \right)^n\to e^{-k}$

we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^n}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( 1-\frac {k} n \right)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k<n}}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac {k} n \right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-k}=\frac{e}{e-1}$$

Comment: (+1) without Hints at last. `:P`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks! The hint was already given! :)

Comment: In your second line, the $O(\frac{1}{n})$ depends on $k$. Therefore you can’t factorize $O(\frac{1}{n})$ in the sum without an additional argument.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes I think you are right, it's a step I need to revise. Thanks

Comment: You could write the sum as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n \operatorname{1}(k<n)$, observe that the sequence $\left[\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n \operatorname{1}(k<n)\right]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing and use the monotone convergence theorem to interchange summation and limit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews By the AM-GM inequality we have $$ \sqrt[n+1]{\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n \cdot 1} \leq \frac{n \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) + 1}{n+1} = 1 - \frac{k}{n+1} \, . $$

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and suggestions, later I’ll to fix that part. Bye

Comment: @gimusi The estimates look fine, but I do not understand how you get $$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \mathrm{e}^{-k \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-1}} = \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k} \mathrm{e}^{k-n} \, . $$

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial My approach was not conclusive, I've revised the proof following your suggestion. Thanks