# $\lim_{n \to+\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{n}}{n^{n}}$ vs $\lim_{x \to+\infty }\int_{1}^{x}\frac{y^{x}}{x^{x}}dy$

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is well known that $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to+\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{n}}{n^{n}}=\frac{e}{e-1}.$$

But if you try to verify this by considering its "continuous" counterpart which is

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to+\infty }\int_{1}^{x}\frac{y^{x}}{x^{x}}dy$$you see that the
result is equal to $1$. Why do we get a different result in this case? Can you find
an explanation? Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Why should those limits be equal?

Comment: Because you may consider an $f(y)=1$ on $[1,2)$ , $f(y)=2$ on$ [2,3)$ e.t.c. and then approximate it with a differentiable function. But it is rather intuition that leads us to believe that!

Comment: Apart from some [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream), the integral is just an approximation for the sum. For example: $\pi^2/6 = \sum 1/n^2 \ne \int_1^\infty dx/x^2 = 1$.

Comment: I agree! This example is very convincing!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164083/42969 for a way to calculate the limit of the sum with the help of integrals.

Comment: The point is that the sum gives $$\lim_{n \to\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{n}}{n^{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{\sqrt n}e^{-l}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty e^{-l}$$
and the integral, in turn, 
$$\lim_{x \to\infty }\int_{1}^{x}\frac{y^{x}}{x^{x}}dy=\lim_{x \to\infty }\int_0^\sqrt x e^{-z}dz=\int_0^\infty e^{-z}dz$$
so, effectively, you compare $\sum_{l=0}^\infty e^{-l}$ and $\int_0^\infty e^{-z}dz$