# Convergence of EM algorithm with continuous hidden variables

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

I am interested in a proof of convergence of EM algorithm when hidden variables are continuous.
I found a proof for a case of discrete  hidden variables, but I cannot find it for continuous case.
Do you know how to prove, or know the reference?
Thanks!

Comment: This is [cross posted](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69914/proof-of-convergence-of-em-algorithm-with-continuous-hidden-variables) on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged, but if you do cross-post, please link to each question from the other(s). That way people don't duplicate effort, and can find any answers given.

Comment: What is the EM algorithm of which you inquire? I immediately think of the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, but that rarely converges (although I give conditions in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156085) under which it does).

Comment: the Expectation Maximization algorithm