# Proving convergence of the Dirichlet Eta function

Tags: analysis, number-theory, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

I've been struggling to prove this for a project as I'm not an expert in the field, so i decided to go back to basics.

The Dirichlet Eta Function is defined by:

$$ \eta (s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}},  \text{  where }  s= \sigma +it $$

The idea i have had is to use the fact that $n^{s} = n^{\sigma}n^{it} = n^{\sigma}(\cos(\ln(n)t)+i\sin(\ln(n)t))$

So we can re-write the sum as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\sigma}(\cos(\ln(n)t)+i\sin(\ln(n)t))} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\sigma}} (\cos(\ln(n)t)-i\sin(\ln(n)t)) $$

So what we end up turning our original problem into two different real series:

$$ \eta (s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\sigma}}\cos(\ln(n)t) - i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\sigma}}\sin(\ln(n)t)) $$

So now my idea is to prove convergence for these two individual real series, which in turn will give me convergence for the complex series. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042512/proof-of-convergence-of-dirichlets-eta-function).

Comment: What you are doing so far looks good.  [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937627/does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-1n-frac-cos-lnnn-epsilon-e?rq=1) also looks related.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt your reference is very cool.

Comment: Such series is convergent for any $s$ with positive real part by Dirichlet's test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test): the sequence $\{(-1)^{n+1}\}_{n\geq 0}$ has bounded partial sums and assuming $s\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $\frac{1}{n^s}$ is decreasing towards zero.

Comment: $n^{-s} - (n+1)^{-s} = s\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s-1}dx = \mathcal{O}(|n^{-s-1}|)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |n^{-s-1}|$ converges for $Re(s) > 0$

Comment: @reuns How is $n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}$ related to $\eta (s)$? Your way seems to be the easiest out there...

Comment: @Tu1 $\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)^{-s}-(2n)^{-s}$