# series with the term $\cos(\ln(x))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Does anyone know about this series? Looks like it converges depending on the value of $a$. Do you know any closed form solution to find the $a$ that makes the series become zero.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos( a \ln(n))}{\sqrt n}$$

Comment: What makes you sure that there exists at least one value of $a$ for which this converges?

Comment: I read that somewhere on a webpage. I remember there were a few values of "a" for which the series was zero. They were found using computers.

Comment: I would enjoy to know the webpage

Comment: If a is not 0. For what values does it obviously not converge.

Comment: It seems to me the series never converges. When $a\neq 0$ take Cauchy slices between $n$ and $(1+\varepsilon)n$. Then the argument in the cosine function will only vary by $a \ln(1+\varepsilon)$ so if you take $n$ big so that $\cos(a\ln(n))$ is near a multiple of $\pi$, the slice will be as big as $C\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Here $\varepsilon$ will only depend on $a$. The case $a=0$ is obvious. The philosophy is that "$\ln$ is constant".

Comment: It diverges for $a=1$ as proved in [robjohn's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/937708/152568) using the  Euler-Maclaurin summation formula. The same method should work for most other $a$.

Comment: This can be obviously rewritten as $Re(\zeta(1/2-ia))=0$. This is a weaker version of the Riemann hypothesis...... -_-

Comment: No it's not. The formula for the Riemann Zeta function is only valid for $\mathfrak{R}(s)>1$.