# Evaluating a summation $\sum_{k=0}^{100} k^2 + k$

Tags: summation

I need help evaluating this:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{100} k^2 + k$$

I'm not sure how to solve this without writing the equation 100 times. and then adding them up.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $\sum k^2$ and $\sum k$?

Comment: not without going through and writing them both out 100 times.

Comment: [This](http://www.cimt.plymouth.ac.uk/projects/mepres/alevel/fpure_ch6.pdf) looks like a pretty good resource for learning about series (and induction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k=[(n^2 + n) / 2]$$

and

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2=[\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)]$$

Adding:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2 + k$$

$$=[\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)] + [(n^2 + n) / 2]$$

In your case, $n=100$, so substitute to get:

$$((1/6)100(101)(201))+(1/2)(10000+100)=343400$$.

The solution provided by @robjohn is much more elegant of course!

If you are into sum history and some neat mathematical logic about sums, you may like this:[Young Gauss and the sum of the first n positive integers](http://mathandmultimedia.com/2010/09/15/sum-first-n-positive-integers/).

Answer (score 4):

Since $(k+1)-k=1$ and $(k+1)^3-k^3=3k^2+3k+1$, we can write a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series):
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\left(k^2+k\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac13\left(3k^2+3k+1\right)-\frac13(1)\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac13\left((k+1)^3-k^3\right)-\frac13\left((k+1)-k\right)\right]\\
&=\frac13(n+1)^3-\frac13(n+1)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Interestingly, the EMSF seems fairly efficient here.

Comment: It is usually so in the case of polynomials. However, it might be a bit out of reach for the OP.

Comment: Yes, it might be a bit much.  But you already had posted a solution using telescoping of $(k+1)^3-k^3$ and i wanted to present an alternative way forward.  +1 for your solution

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What does $(k+1)^3 -k^3$ equal and what happens when you add this up as $k$ varies between one and one hundred?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to apply the [Euler-Mclaurin Sum Fromula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula).

To that end, let $f(x)=x^2+x$.  Then, $f'(x)=2x+1$, $f''(x)=2$, and all higher-order derivatives are zero.

Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nf(n)&=\int_0^nf(x)\,dx+\frac12(f(n)-f(0))+\frac{1}{12}(f'(n)-f'(0))\\\\
&=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac12(n^2+n)+\frac16 n\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac13 n(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156085), the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula is finite on polynomials, and therefore, converges. In fact the Fourier Transform of a polynomial is a constant coefficient differential operator applied to the Dirac delta distribution; therefore it is supported in $(-1,1)$. Thus, it converges for that reason, too. (+1)

Comment: @ronjon +1 for the comment and insight along with the associated reference

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{100} k^2+k=2\sum_{k=0}^{100}\binom {k+1}2=2\binom {102}3
=\frac{102\cdot 101\cdot 100}3\qquad\blacksquare$$